# Get points of intersection of rectangles Not O(n²) and OutOfMemory

Tags: java, geometry

I'm trying to get the points of intersection of two rectangles. I have a method that works but when i test it with an algorithm for 40000 rectangles, i get an OutOfMemory error. The amount of times i check for intersections is perfectly O(n²), but the time it takes is not.
I think the out of memory is just because there are too many objects, but that the time it takes is not O(n²) (tested with a doubling test) does not make sense to me, and i can't figure out why it is doing that.

This is my code for getting the intersection

```
 public void getIntersections(Rectangle r, Collection<double[]> c) {

    x1 = Math.max(this.getLowerLeftX(), r.getLowerLeftX());
    y1 = Math.max(this.getLowerLeftY(), r.getLowerLeftY());

    x2 = Math.min(this.getUpperRightX(), r.getUpperRightX());
    y2 = Math.min(this.getUpperRightY(), r.getUpperRightY());


    if(this.contains(x1,y1) && r.contains(x1,y1)) {
        inter[0] = x1;
        inter[1] = y1;
        c.add(inter.clone());
    }

    if(this.contains(x1,y2) && r.contains(x1,y2)){
        inter[0] = x1;
        inter[1] = y2;
        c.add(inter.clone());
    }

    if(this.contains(x2,y1) && r.contains(x2,y1)){
        inter[0] = x2;
        inter[1] = y1;
        c.add(inter.clone());
    }

    if(this.contains(x2,y2) && r.contains(x2,y2)){
        inter[0] = x2;
        inter[1] = y2;
        c.add(inter.clone());
    }
}
```

I tried to make this as memory and cpu efficient, but still it doesn't work as it should.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The algorithm that calls this function:

```
public void execute() {
    List<Rectangle> rectangles = this.getRectangles();
    Queue<Rectangle> q = new LinkedList<Rectangle>();
    q.addAll(rectangles);
    System.out.println(q.size());
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        Rectangle check_rect = q.poll();
        for (Rectangle rect: q) {
            check_rect.getIntersections(rect, this.getIntersections());
        }
    }
}
```

Helper functions:

```
public boolean contains(double x, double y){
    return ((x == this.getLowerLeftX() || x == this.getUpperRightX()) ||
            (y == this.getLowerLeftY() || y == this.getUpperRightY())) &&
            x >= this.getLowerLeftX() && x <= this.getUpperRightX() &&
            y >= this.getLowerLeftY() && y <= this.getUpperRightY();
}
```

For the collection of intersections i use:

```
this.intersections = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

The outOfMemory Exception always happens when it tries to enlarge the ArrayDeque<>(), which only stores the intersection points in double[2]. So it seems that there are just too many intersections between the 40000 rectangles.
Another problem seems to be that the iteration before it runs out of memory, it really slows down, is this because of swapping or other memory management?

Comment: Have you looked at dynamics of performance degradation (1000, 5000, 10000 rectangles)? Also you should provide the code that invokes this method, because issue may be there. Also your method works on side-effects, which considered to be bad practice. Usually you want to return a new intersection object, and not manipulate input and global variables.

Comment: Could you provide implementations of all the methods used here? That means all the `getLowerRight`, `getUpperLeft` etc. methods and the `contains` method. Additionally please include the declaration of `inter` array

Comment: I added more info so you can see what i'm doing.

Comment: Since you didn't answer to my comment I'll clarify. My assumption is that you have not enough memory to calculate the answer, so try invoking your code for 1k, 5k, 10k rectangles, and then take a look at memory consumption at the end of invocation: `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`. If it becomes small at the amount of rectangles, which is near to the margin at which program stops working, - try increasing the amount of memory available using`-Xmx` VM flag.

Comment: 40000 Rectangles is not so much these days. I think it is a good opportunity for you to use the memory tools available on the java platform, to find out what type of objects make the problem.

Comment: @user3707125 Increasing the memory works, but it seems that the time is no longer O(n²) for the larger amounts, i assume this is because of memory management in windows?

Comment: remove the .clone()  in the intersection method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, here it is: Your algorithm is more or less quadratic. If you make multiple runs with twice as many elements in each run as the previous run and compute quotients of the durations of pairs of consequent runs, you will find that it falls more or less between 3.5 and 4.5 (discarding runs with few elements, you need a couple of thousands to make it stable enough).

The problem is that 20K is just fine, but multiplying it by 2 to get to 40K changes something.

The thing that is changed is the ability of the JVM to hold all the results in its heap. Just as user3707125 said. I've run your algorithm with 51200 rectangles.

You can the result here:[image: CPU and heap usage in a failed run]

After the heap is full the Garbage Collector goes into frenzy trying to free some memory, but there's nothing to be freed - all the objects are reachable. After a while you get an `OutOfMemoryException` with message "GC overhead limit exceeded". That means that GC used too much time but reclaimed too little memory (I think that defaults are 98% of CPU time and 2% of the heap).

You can see the structure of the heap here:[image: heap dump just before the failure]

As you can see, the double[] objects containing the coordinates take up most of the heap, followed by Object[] - that would be the internal array of ArrayDeque.

What can you do? You have to increase the heap size of the JVM when you run the app, just as user3707125 said. You do that by passing e.g. `-Xmx8g` flag as a VM option. `8g` here means 8 gigabytes.

You can see a run with that option here:[image: CPU and heap usage of a successful run]

I took it after the process successfully finished.

The other thing that you could do is to think about how could you reduce the memory footprint. Maybe use floats instead of doubles? You could write a custom solution for a dynamic array of `doubles` (but not `Doubles`! Use the primitives here) and keep a flat structure, i.e. instead of having every point as a separate array of two doubles, keep all of them side by side in the dynamic double array (two points would take up 4 slots). That would eliminate the need for one layer of pointers which take 8 bytes per pointer (assuming 64bit architecture) and array lengths (4 bytes), which adds up to a lot of memory. Still, no matter how would you tune the space usage of you algorithm, increasing the number of rectangles will eat the memory very fast. Meier said that 40000 rectangles is not much, but I assume that your test data has many intersections - that means that the amount of data that you need to store is O(n²), not just the time it takes to compute it.

Comment: I've solved the problem by writing the data to an output file, instead of keeping it in a datastructure. Now the memory exception doesn't occur anymore because the application only calculates the intersections and doesn't keep track of them anymore.